# How to change the border color of some cells in DataGridView?

Tags: winforms, datagridview

I need to programming change the border color of some cells in the CellFormatting event. Can the board color of an individual cell be changed?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewadvancedborderstyle.aspx

Answer (score 11):

You can draw a rectangle. In this example I put a red boder on the selected cells.

```
private void dataGridView_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RowIndex >= 0 && e.ColumnIndex >= 0)
    {
        if (dataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Selected == true)
        {
            e.Paint(e.CellBounds, DataGridViewPaintParts.All & ~DataGridViewPaintParts.Border);
            using (Pen p = new Pen(Color.Red, 1))
            {
                Rectangle rect = e.CellBounds;
                rect.Width -= 2;
                rect.Height -= 2;
                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(p, rect);
            }
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This example works only if the cell is selected.  What if I need to create several rectangles?

Comment: @doro You can just change the conditional: selected == true

Comment: How to apply the same effect to RowHeightChanged and ColumnWidthChanged events, for example?

Answer (score 1):

MSDN describes a method where you can inherit from the DataGridView to override the default border styles: [DataGridViewAdvancedBorderStyle Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewadvancedborderstyle(v=vs.110).aspx)

The painting method above is simpler, though.